# Why transferring Encrypted data from server to client the decryption doesnt work - The inputdata is not complete block

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption

I'm trying to send and receive encrypted data from clients to asp.Net.
Everythings works fine before the encryption (AES).
Now I can pass the encrypted data from client to server and to decrypt it.
But for some reason, the same algorithm when I pass the data from server to client I cant decrypt it, and I get the error - The input data is not complete block.

Does someone can light me or explain what I miss? or Why is it happend?
the code for the encryption\decryption:

```
public string Encryption(string i_MessageBytes)
{
    string encryptedMessage = string.Empty;

    using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aes.Key = m_ClientKey;
        m_IV = aes.IV;
        ClientIV = Convert.ToBase64String(m_IV);

        // Encrypt the message 
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                byte[] plaintextMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i_MessageBytes);
                cs.Write(plaintextMessage, 0, plaintextMessage.Length);
                cs.Flush();
                cs.Close();
            }   

            encryptedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());                    
        }
    }

    return encryptedMessage;
}

public string Decryption(string i_Message)
{
    string originalMessage = string.Empty;

    using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aes.Key = m_ServerKey;
        aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ClientIV);
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        byte[] messageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(i_Message);

        // Decrypt the message 
        using (MemoryStream plaintext = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(plaintext, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
                originalMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext.ToArray());                        
            }

        }
    }
    return originalMessage;
}
```

((The property ClientIV and the member class m_ClientKey, m_ServerKey are in the correct places ))

In the server side at the api controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(RegisterUser user)
    {
        var userItem = s_Repository.Add(user);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.Created, EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.Security.Encryption(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userItem)));
        response.Headers.Add("ServerIV", EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.Security.ServerIV);

        string uri = Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = userItem.ID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
```

In the client side

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                s_Result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                string[] ivString = httpResponse.Headers.GetValues("Sec-Key");
                s_StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode;
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created && ivString.Count() != 0)
                {
                    s_CollectingPublicKiesProcessCompleted = true;
                    s_ECDH.ServerIV = ivString.First();
                    UserInfoSaverSingleton.UserInfoInstance.PasswordForServerAndEncryption = i_UserDetails.Password;
                    UserInfoSaverSingleton.UserInfoInstance.Save();

                    string userFromServer = s_ECDH.Decryption(s_Result);
                    s_UserDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetailsForConnectingToContactsManagerServer>(userFromServer);
                    s_ModelDialogService.ShowDialog(s_Dialog, new MessageBoxViewModel() { Message = string.Format("Registration Complete"), Buttons = eMessageBoxButtons.Ok, MessageType = eMessageBoxType.Information, Title = string.Format("") });
                }
```

Comment: Have you ensured that you're reading the entire string before attempting to decrypt it? Since your question is about the network transport, please post some code relevant to that.

Comment: I can see that plaintext.ToArray() in the Encryption func has 192 bytes, but in the Decryption func the messageBytes has 258. But I have no idea why thats happend.

Comment: We're missing the code that is in between. Note that client server models are very vulnerable to man in the middle and padding oracle attacks. Just performing encryption is not going to cut it. Use TLS instead. For now, make sure your ciphertext is identical at both sides first.

Comment: "We're missing the code that is in between."@owlstead what do you mean? From the PostUser the message goes to the part I post which is in the client side. The encryption thing is really new for me and I need something that will work also on communication between web api (without a website) and mobile phones, so I thought working with Http will works with everydvice.

Comment: I forgot to mention but the ciphertext is the same in both sides. And one more thing if the Aes is not the right solution for me I open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Now it works.

Server side:

public string Encryption(string i_Message)
        {
            string encryptedMessage = string.Empty;

```
        using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = m_ServerKey;
            m_IV = aes.IV;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            ServerIV = Convert.ToBase64String(m_IV);                

            // Encrypt the message 
            using (MemoryStream plaintext = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(plaintext, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(i_Message);                    
                    cs.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                    cs.Flush();
                    cs.Close();
                }

                encryptedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(plaintext.ToArray());                    
            }
        }
        return encryptedMessage;
    }
```

Client side:

```
  public string Decryption(string i_Message)
    {
        string originalMessage = string.Empty;

        using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = m_ClientKey;
            aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ServerIV);
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;            

            string message = i_Message.Substring(1, i_Message.Length - 2);
            byte[] messageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(message);

            // Decrypt the message 
            using (MemoryStream plaintext = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(plaintext, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                    cs.Close();

                    originalMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }

        return originalMessage;
    }
```

I had two problems:

1. The result of the encryption (string) that pass from server to client got "\" as the string begins and ends. I dont know why if someone knows let me know, so if it wasn't in the server 
   it not important so I removed it.
2. KEEPING STRINGS TYPES CONVERTING ORDER - I didn't notice that I convert between utf8 and base64 in the wrong order.

I hope someone will learn from my mistakes.